# Django Form Not Posting to SQL

Tags: python, django, forms, sqlite

I have a page where an item from a list nested within my form can be favorited, it redirects back to the same page following what should be an update to the database, then it shows a star next to the item. While this should work fine my form doesn't change the DB at all. I am confident it is not the html rendering since when I manually change the field in the admin panel it renders fine. What is causing this to not post?

view.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from .models import Album, Song

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    all_albums = Album.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('music/index.html')
    context = {'all_albums' : all_albums,} 
    return render(request, 'music/index.html', context)

def detail(request, album_id):
    album = get_object_or_404(Album, pk=album_id)
    return render(request, 'music/detail.html', {'album' : album})

def favorite(request, album_id):
    album = get_object_or_404(Album, pk=album_id)
    print("favorite stuff happens here")
    try:
        selected_song = album.song_set.get(pk=int(request.POST['song']))
    except (KeyError, Song.DoesNotExist):
        return render(request, 'music/detail.html', {
            'album' : album,
            'error_message': 'Did not select a valid song'
            })
    else:
        selected_song.favorite = True
        selected_song.save()
        return render(request, 'music/detail.html', {'album' : album})
```

```html
<img src="{{album.album_logo}}">

<h1>{{album.album_title}} </h1>
<h2>{{album.artist}} </h2>

{% if error_message %}
 <p><strong> {{error_message}} </strong></p>
{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'music:favorite' album.id %}" method="post">
 {% csrf_token %}
 {% for song in album.song_set.all %}
  <input type="radio" id="song{{forloop.counter}}" name="song" value="{{song.id}}" />
  <label for="song{{forloop.counter}}">
   <span>{{song.song_title}}
   {% if song.is_favorite %}
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/b9b13Rd.png" />
   {% endif %}
  </span>
  </label><br>
 {% endfor %}
 <input type="submit" value="Favorite">
</form>
```

model.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    album_logo = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_title + ' -- ' + self.artist

class Song(models.Model):
    # on delete this deletes this entry
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_type = models.CharField(max_length=4)
    song_title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.song_title
```

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

app_name = 'music'

urlpatterns = [
    # /music/
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),

    # /music/<album_id>/
    url(r'^(\d+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),

    # logic for favoriting adjusts model and redirects to same place
    # /music/<album_id>/favorite
    url(r'^(\d+)/favorite/$', views.favorite, name='favorite'),
]
```

Comment: Well, your model Song column named `is_favorite` adn you set True for `favorite`

Comment: *&%$, yea you're right, now its working